# How can i align the vertex to a surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

first time writing here in stackexchange since most of the time i find the answer on other people's posts

I have a mesh made of a lot of vertex, i had do manualy remove and add some vertex after the surface was already made and now it looks kind of bumpy, it has smooth shading on and still
I want to align the vertex to the shape of the surface to smooth them, is there a way i can do this?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hello, please share your file so that we can try? https://pasteall.org/blend/ ... maybe grid fill would work, it depends on your topology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) select all vertices in edit mode with your bumpy face

2.) then press this + button

[image]

3.) then tap <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>

4.) enjoy the flat surface

tutorial: https://youtu.be/4QJkM2Ve6qs (just be a little bit patient if it isn't uploaded, my upload speed is pretty slow)

Comment: Well, that works perfect for a surface that is flat, but this one is curve-ish, not the answer that i was lokking for but i appreciate it since i didnt know how to do this in blender 2.9

Comment: ah ok, sorry, missed that it was curved. Then you can try it with sculpting -> flatten